# How to restrict the Provider Hosted App installation on subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, provider-hosted-app, sub-site

I have created a Provider Hosted App for SharePoint On-Premises and SharePoint Online.

My requirement is that this app should only installed if its a Site Collection. If it is a Site within a Site Collection then in that case this app should not installed.

So How Can I protect a Provider Hosted App from being install in sub site?

**Proposed Approach**

---

I have gone through [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/create-an-add-in-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins) and [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/handle-events-in-sharepoint-add-ins#Rollback). Now What I am thinking, Can I capture an app installed event, and once the app is installed, I will check whether the Host web is Site Collection or Sub Site, and If its Sub Site then I will rollback the installation.

So again my question arise, can I uninstall the installed Add-In in `AppInstalled` event?